# Expand columns to see full jobname in Slurm

Tags: slurm, sacct

Is it possible to expand the number of characters used in the `JobName` column of the command `sacct` in SLURM?

For example, I currently have:

```
       JobID    JobName    Elapsed      NCPUS   NTasks      State 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- 
12345      lengthy_na+   00:00:01         4         1      FAILED
```

and I would like:

```
       JobID    JobName    Elapsed      NCPUS   NTasks      State 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- 
12345      lengthy_name   00:00:01         4         1      FAILED
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should use the format option, with:

```
sacct --helpformat
```

you'll see the parameters to show, for instance:

```
sacct --format="JobID,JobName%30"
```

will print the job id and the name up to 30 characters:

```
       JobID                        JobName
------------ ------------------------------
19009                                  bash
19010                             launch.sh
19010.0                     hydra_pmi_proxy
19010.1                     hydra_pmi_proxy
```

Now, you can customize your own output.

Comment: do we really need to type this very long string everytime we want to see a list of running jobs and their full names? Not to mention that run-time and other details such as memory usage would require an even longer command

Comment: @par: Yes, because the default format is definded with a limit. However, you can define a variable (in this case `SACCT_FORMAT`) to override the default behaviour.

Comment: Afterwards how can I get complete information related to each individual job using their id? @Bub Espinja

Comment: You always can use "sacct -j <id> --long" for that purpose.

Comment: @Parsa I have this in my ~/.bashrc: ```alias sl='SLURM_TIME_FORMAT="%d %H:%M:%S" sacct -X --format=JobID,JobName%12,Priority,Submit%12,Start%12,Elapsed,NCPU,CPUTime,ExitCode,State'```  Please excuse the weird line wraps due to Stack Overflow :(

Comment: Thank you @DuncanMacIntyre

Answer (score 63):

To retrieve my list of SLURM jobs running I use the default format with 30 characters showing for job names using the bash command below:

```sh
squeue --format="%.18i %.9P %.30j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.9l %.6D %R" --me
```

If you want to show more job name characters simply change the number of `%.30j`.

Comment: Hint: I added this (using `alias squeue='squeue --format="..."'`) to my .bashrc to preserve my sanity.

Comment: @MrArsGravis: In fact you do not need to alias that. Simply put the format in the environment variable `SQUEUE_FORMAT`